# Simplest way to find text by regex and replace by lookup table

Tags: awk, replace, lookup-tables

A legacy web application needs to be internationalized. Error messages are currently written inside source code in this way:

```
addErrorMessage("some text here");
```

These signs can be easily found and extracted using regex. They should be replaced with something like this:

```
addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle", lcale).getString("key for text here"));
```

The correspondence between **key for text here** and **some text here** will be in a .property file.

According to some linux guru it can be achieved using awk, but I don't know anything about it. I can write a small application to do that task but it could be overkill. Are there ide plugin or existing applications for this goal ?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v TextOrg='some text here' -v key='key for text here' ' "addErrorMessage(\"" TextOrg "\")" {
   gsub( "addErrorMessage(\"" TextOrg "\")" \
       , "addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle(\"/Bundle\", lcale).getString(\"" key "\"))")
   }
   7
   ' YourFile
```

this is one way for a specific combination. Be carefful with:

- assignation of value (`-v ...` that are constraint by shell interpretation in this case)
- gsub is using regex to find, so your text need to be treated with this constraint (ex: `"this f***ing text"` -> `"this f\*\*\*ing text"` )

You certainly want to do if for several peer.

her with a file conatinaing peers

assuming that Trad.txt is a file that containt a series of 2 lines 1st, original text, second the key (to avoid some chara as separator that need complexe escape sequence interpretation if used)

ex: Trad.txt

```
some text
key text
other text
other key
```

sample code (simple, no exhaustive security, ...) Not tested, but for the concept with awk

```
awk '
   # for first file only
   FNR == NR {
      # keep in memory first line as text to change
      if ( NR % 2 ) TextOrg = $0
       else {
          # load in array the key corresponding (index is the text to change)
          Key[ TextOrg] = $0
          Len[ TextOrg] = length( addErrorMessage(\"" $0 "\")"
          }
      # don't go further in script for this line
      next
      }

   # this point and further is reach only by second file 

   # if addError is found
   /addErrorMessage(".*")/{
      # try with each peer if there is a change (a more complex loop is more perfomant checking just necessary replacement but this one do the job)
      for( TextOrg in Key) {
         # to avoid regex interpretation
         # Assuming for this sample code that there is 1 replace (loop is needed normaly)
         # try a find of text (return the place where)
         Here = index( addErrorMessage(\"" TextOrg "\")", $0)
         if( Here > 0) { 
            # got a match, replace the substring be recreating a full one
            $0 = substr( $0, 1, Here) \
                 "addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle(\"/Bundle\", lcale).getString(\"" Key[ TextOrg] "\"))") \
                 substr( $0, Here + Len[ TextOrg])
            }
      }           
   }

   # print the line in his current state (modified or not)
   7
   ' Trad.txt YourFile
```

Finally, this is a workaround solution because lot of special case could occurs like `"ref: function addErrorMessage(\" ...\") bla bla"` will be an issue, or space inside `()` not treated here, or cutted line insdie `()`,  ...